# cannot call javascript function inside click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div like this that is loaded via ajax:

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton submit_data">Click here to submit</a>
</div>
```

In the same file in which I have the div, I have a script like this:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#container').on('click', 'a.submit_data', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(test());
        });

        function test()
        {
            return 'This is a test';
        }
    });
</script>
```

The problem I have is when I call my function `test()` in the callback of the click event like I did above, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` when I click on my button (so I don't even get my alert). But if I call my `test()` function outside of the click handler, everything works as expected.

Dpes anybody know why this is happening please?

Thank you

Comment: Not reproducible: http://jsfiddle.net/PP7Pj/

Comment: it works in a fiddle using jquery 1.10.1

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: Works with jQuery 2.x, too http://jsfiddle.net/RfSSE/ (assuming browser support)

Comment: Are there any other event listeners attached to this element?

Comment: i know this is old, but i just ran in a same situation. as there is a "Type Error", the variable test must have been declared as something else before. at least in my case, i had a double assignment. look out for test being already declared.

Answer (score -1):

Does this help? I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for. I cleaned up the script and the click event.

[Codepen sketch](http://cdpn.io/vohsG)

**jQuery**

```
$('.submit-data').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert(myFunction());
});

var myFunction = function(){
  return 'This is a test';
}
```

**HTML** Changed the `submit_data` class to `submit-data` for better selector convention.

```
<div id="container">
  <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton submit-data">Click here to submit</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the difference between your and OP's scripts?